# Publish .Net project on local system occur error <sessionState timeout="540" />

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis

When i publish .Net project on local IIS server it will occur an error but on visual studio it is runing perfect
what will be the error i searched but not find suitable solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Per the error message, is the application configured properly in the IIS server? The error message seems to point to the app not being properly registered in IIS.